# Двумерные фигуры java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!

Не мог бы кто-нибудь пояснить новичку, что такое двумерные фигуры в java. В Интернете, к сожалению, информации не нашла. )

Comment: Имеется ввиду в Java Swing?

Comment: Нет, изучаем просто Java)@Rams666

Comment: @liliya, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

[@liliya](/users/24332/liliya), нет такого понятия как "двумерные фигуры в java". Есть ряд библиотек, позволяющих их рисовать. Некоторые из них (например, Swing) поставляется вместе с JDK, их можно начинать использовать "из коробки". Другие нужно загружать и подключать к проекту отдельно. Судя по вашей фразе

> Нет, изучаем просто Java

вам нужен именно Swing. Например, [эта статья](http://study-and-dev.com/blog/java_swing_1/) описывает основы рисования в Swing. Ищите дополнительную информацию по запросу "[swing рисование фигур](https://www.google.by/search?q=swing+%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80)" и в [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/package-summary.html) Java.

Comment: @fori1ton спасибо